# Why do I get "TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given" when using super() to initialize the base class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some code to create a class hierarchy:

```
class LogicGate:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.label = n
        self.output = None

class BinaryGate(LogicGate):
    def __init__(self, n):
        LogicGate.__init__(self, n)
        self.pinA = None
        self.pinB = None

class AndGate(BinaryGate):
    def __init__(self, n):
        super(AndGate, self).__init__(self, n)
```

But when I try to create an `AndGate`, an error occurs:

```
>>> AndGate('example')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
TypeError: BinaryGate.__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

What is wrong with the code? Why does the error claim that 3 arguments are being given to `BinaryGate.__init__()`? How should I properly use `super` instead?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27134600/860421

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass `self` here:

```
super(AndGate,self).__init__(self,n)
```

It should be

```
super(AndGate,self).__init__(n)
```

Answer (score 4):

When using `super`, `self` is passed automatically.

Also, in Python3.3 and above, `super` does not even need to receive arguments to know from which class it is being called. You can simply do this.

```
super().__init__(n)
```

This greatly improves maintainability, so it would be the prefered approach.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Python 3.3 and above, you should replace

```
LogicGate.__init__(self,n)
```

with

```
super().__init__(n)
```

It is better to use this format when ever you want to call super class constructor.